# How do I structure a 2D platform level?

Tags: game-design, javascript, html5, platformer

I'm doing a 2D platformer but I don't know how they are usually built.

The approach I'm looking at is making it tilebased, with ground tiles on bottom row, then platforms on some places in "mid-air" within the array.

Then some physics to add gravity to pull the player down if airborn, and just scroll the map horizontally and check for collisions.

Am I on the right track? Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that the graphics are pixelated if you want to get anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to share a link with you that someone else had shared with me:

http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/

This page covers several approaches as to how one might implement 2d platformers with both basic and some more advanced mechanics. It doesn't give you straight up code but it does a fantastic job at explaining the techniques so that you should be able to code it without too much trouble.

Comment: That article is very helpful.  It doesn't mention background scrolling, though, which can in some cases be challenging.  I think the important thing to remember with regards to scrolling is that your tiles (or non-tiled world) have to be translated into pixel positions first based on where the camera is.  While most of my programming has been in 3D, it stands to reason that in 2D games you still want to mostly disassociate the camera from the world.  In pure side-scrolling platformers you may end up locking the camera vertically to the character while giving them some "play" horizontally, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/), which is a great free map editor. You can build your own level with it, and then load the output file (a XML) into your application (generally Tiled compacts everything with gzip and then converts to base64, but there are libraries to load that).

As for the code, yes. You could see it as a big array.

Answer (score 2):

I would buy the Level UP book: [http://www.amazon.com/Level-Up-Guide-Great-Design/dp/047068867X/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047068867X)
This is the only one with a broken spine & dog eared pages currently on my shelf.

Also read the author's blog for awesome ideas, particularly his Platformer Primer: http://mrbossdesign.blogspot.ca/2008/10/platformer-primer.html